# Dose the rviz View-Oriented Text support UTF-8 caption?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd like to display some text markers with Chinese characters in rviz.

So I tried:

```
marker.text  = text.encode('UTF-8')
```

and the marker.text therefor in the u'\u5b57\u8282' form.

But nothing pop out.

Any suggestion to make it work?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232881/dose-the-rviz-view-oriented-text-support-utf-8-caption?/) by [SHI.ZP](https://answers.ros.org/users/25720/shi.zp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, rviz does not handle UTF-8 text. It only handles a portion of the ASCII character set.

There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1002) for this on the rviz bug tracker.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0